# Pass javascript array to php by using curly braces key name

Tags: php, jquery

My js code:

```
$(function(){
    var arr = new Array('jj', 'kk', 'oo');
    $.post('test12.php', {'arr[]': arr}, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
echo print_r($_POST['arr']);
```

The thing is,$.post receive a key named 'arr[]',it should be used in PHP as 'arr[]' instead of 'arr',but '$_POST['arr[]']' doesn't work,'arr' works.Which seems that Jquery might do something with curly braces '[]' before sending something to PHP.

Secondly,when I remove the single quotas around 'arr[]',PHP can not receive anything by using $_POST['arr'];,**I don't know why?**

Doing this task in a traditional way with no curly braces:

```
$.post('test12.php', {arr: arr}, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

It works fine.

So when sending javascript array to PHP,**why bothering using single quote and curly braces like**

```
'arr[]'
```

instead of using a concise way like arr:arr

My return result is

```
Array(
   [0]=>jj
   [1]=>kk
   [2]=>oo
)
1
```

**Notice there is a 1 under the array,why?**

Comment: Minor note `[]` are not curly braces they are called square brackets.  `{}` are curly braces

Comment: When using jQuery you don't do single quotes or square brackets. jQuery handles it for you.  The only time you use square brackets is when it's in an input field like: `<input name="arr[]" value="jj" /><input name="arr[]" value="kk" /><input name="arr[]" value="oo" />`

Answer (score 0):

when you send a variable to php that has a name that resembles php array syntax, php auto-parses it into an array for you. the feature is lightly documented:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

you can't turn the feature off, although you can manually parse the raw binary input stream if youre really determined.

additional example

```
<input name="foo[bar][3][baz]" value="d">
```

is accessed like the closest php equivalent

```
$_POST['foo']['bar'][3]['baz']
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery serializes your request automatically in a way that PHP understands it, so this:

```
{arr: [1,2,3]}
```

Is automatically serialized as `arr[]=1&arr[]=2&arr[]=3` behind the scenes and in PHP you can access it via `$_POST['arr']` as an array.

The reason why you see the extra `1` at the end is because you `echo` the result of `print_r()`, which is `true`. You can just have this code:

```
print_r($_POST['arr']);
```